# Binary representation, how do I get to the 'relevant bits'?

Tags: c++

There are a couple of tutorials on google, but most show how to print binary representation of a number and do so by printing the whole 16/32 bits.

My question is how do you find out which is the most significant bit that is 1 and work(not necessarily print them) with those after it, itself included.

Comment: [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: You might be interested in the  shift operators (`<<` and `>>`) as well as the bitwise AND operator (`&`).

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add some examples. The question is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the bits and check each bit's value:

```
uint data = 0x4AC;

for (auto i = 1, c = 0; c < sizeof(uint)*8; i = i << 1, ++c)
{
    if ((data & i) > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "bit " << i <<" is 1" << std::endl;
    }
}

bit 4 is 1
bit 8 is 1
bit 32 is 1
bit 128 is 1
bit 1024 is 1
```

Comment: note you should be using uint as the msb will be the sign bit

Comment: What is `qDebug`? And instead of commenting your own answer, you should [edit]  it.

Comment: Bits are traditionally numbered according to their position (the least significant bit being bit zero), not the corresponding value.